# Quartz Spring boot: environment property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I've this code in order to populate my properties:

```
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

`quartz.properties` is like:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.host = localhost
```

The problem is that according to current environtment (loc, dev...), I need this property is one or another.

We are looking for a way to parameterize this value. Something like:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.host = ${jobHost}
```

where, `jobHost` would contain the environment related host.

I hope I've explained so well.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've tried setting my `jobHost` variable on commandline:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=scheduler-props.properties,--jobHost=localhost
```

but it gets me:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: ${jobHost}

it seems `jobHost` is not resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot: Property file with place holder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113717/spring-boot-property-file-with-place-holder)

Comment: delete one of the post, don't create duplicates

Answer (score 0):

The good way of achieving this is by externalizing configuration. Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html for details.

Comment: Could you take a look on post?

Comment: I don't think you can pass/append properties directly like the way you mentioned above. You can create dev.properties where you can add your host and I am sure it should be resolved as usual.

Comment: I've also tried addint it on `application.properties`. It fails again...

Comment: I guess you have org.quartz.jobStore.host = ${jobHost} in you application.properties file and It wont get resolved within that from other files. Consider injecting the property directly inside your xml like value="${jobHost}" or java class using @Value("${jobHost:myDevhost}"). I hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all I got your problem but if you want to programmatically resolve the hostname then

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

is the way to go

Otherwise you can programmatically retrieve a "System property" (`System.getProperty(String name)`) passed to your program using -Dpropertyname=value or an "Environment variable" (`System.getenv(String name)`).

```
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
  PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
  propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
  propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
  final Properties prop = propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
  prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.host", System.getProperty("jobHost");
  return prop
}
```