# Spring boot: Property file with place holder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm loading a property file like using this code:

```
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

`quartz.properties` is like:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.host = ${jobHost}
```

I've tried setting my `jobHost` variable `application.properties` file:

```
jobHost = localhost
```

but it gets me:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: ${jobHost}

it seems `jobHost` is not resolved.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain why do you need in this way? you want to override the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Since you directly handle the `Properties`, the `${jobHost}` doesn't get resolved.

You can use [ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "xxx")
public class QuartzConfigProperties {
    // Fields go here
}
```

or

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties")
public class QuartzConfigProperties {

    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.host}")
    private String host;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: I guess I need to fill up this class with some fields. Do I need to add `jobHost`?

Comment: @Jordi Yes. For simplicity I suggest you to use the second alternative

Comment: As far I've figured out, you are setting on `host` field the value of `org.quartz.jobStore.host`. What I need is to set the `org.quartz.jobStore.host` the value of `jobHost`...

Comment: @Jordi No, that's how `@Value` works. Must be something like `${the key from .properties file}`. But you can set also `${jobHost}`

Answer (score 0):

Storing property in more than one place can be confusing for other programmers.
And the keys should be unique to preserve consistency
I recommend to decide from which property file you want to read the value.

**1. Reading from application.properties**
See example here:

[How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Access it from any `@Component` as @Eugen Covaci suggested with `@Value`:

```
@Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.host}")
private String name;
```

**2. Reading from quartz.properties**
This way you are open for new properties (I assume you will have more if you created a separate property file).
See my example below:

**QuartzProperties POJO (each field is a property)**

```
    public class QuartzProperties {

    private String jobHost;

    public String getJobHost() { return jobHost; }

    public void setJobHost(String jobHost) { this.jobHost = jobHost; }
}
```

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties")
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Value("${org.quartz.jobStore.host}")
    String jobHost;
    //other properties for Quartz here
    @Bean
    public QuartzProperties quartzProperties(){
        QuartzProperties quartzProperties = new QuartzProperties();
        quartzProperties.setJobHost(jobHost);
        //setters for other properties here
        return quartzProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Access it from any `@Component` by `quartzProperties.getJobHost()`.

I just named it as quartzProperties and QuartzConfig but it can be jobStoreProperties or JobStoreConfig. Depends on the purpose of these properties.

Or if you want to create 2 profiles (dev & test for example) you could create them following the [Spring YAML Configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml)

Or you can externalize the configuration as an environment variable/pass it as a command line argument.
[Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)